# Top commas in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am learning Gnu Make and don't understand the construction. Actually wondering what parameters are in quotes? This entry is the first in the Makefile.

```
LIBLORAGW_VERSION := `cat ../VERSION`
```

Answer (score 1):

Backticks `` ` ` `` are shell syntax to return enclosed command output as a string.

So that, this line executes `cat ../VERSION`, grabs its output and assigns it to `LIBLORAGW_VERSION`

Upd: Yes, the explanation above is a simplified "it looks like" but is not correct in details. See MadScientist's comment and try this

```makefile
DATE=`date`

all:
    $(info DATE is $(DATE))
    @echo DATE is $(DATE)
```

Comment: The important thing to understand is that these are SHELL syntax.  They mean nothing special to GNU make.  You're basically just setting this variable to the literal string containing the backquotes.  However, most likely when you USE this variable in a recipe, something like `$(LIBLORAGW_VERSION)`, then it expands to the backquoted string and is passed to the shell, and the shell handles it.